# Using Apollo's MockedProvider why don't the component's props get populated with result?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

Following some ideas from [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/jbaxleyiii/b3634aeeab7bdb80ed4119ea5a07ba4a), I am unable to get a component test to work as expected.

Everything seems to work except the `props` never get populated with the `data` from the response.

Any reason why this isn't working as I expect it to?

Here is the simplest real-world example I could make based on an existing component:

```
// test-component.js
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import userQuery from './userQuery.graphql';

function TestComponent (props) {
    console.log('props from component', props); // eslint-disable-line
    return <div>The component...</div>;
}

export default graphql(userQuery)(TestComponent);

// userQuery.graphql
query userQuery {
    user {
        items {
            firstName
            id
            lastName
        }
    }
}

// test-component-test.js
import React from 'react';
import { MockedProvider } from 'react-apollo/lib/test-utils';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';
import userQuery from '../userQuery.graphql';
import { TestComponent } from '../';

const mockedData = {
    user: {
        items: [
            {
                firstName: 'userF',
                id: 'hhhh-gggg-iiii',
                lastName: 'userL',
            }
        ]
    }
};

describe('<TestComponent />', () => {
    describe('Markup should stay consistent', () => {
        const component = (
            <MockedProvider
                mocks={[
                    {
                        request: {
                            query: userQuery
                        },
                        result: { data: mockedData }
                    },
                ]}
                store={{
                    getState: () => {},
                    dispatch: () => {},
                    subscribe: () => {},
                }}
            >
                <TestComponent />
            </MockedProvider>
        );

        const mountedComponent = mount(component);

        it('should not have any changes without a new snapshot', () => {
            const tree = toJson(mountedComponent);
            expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
        });
    });
});

// console.log output during lifecycle
props from component { data:
 { variables: { offset: null, limit: null },
   refetch: [Function: bound ],
   fetchMore: [Function: bound ],
   updateQuery: [Function: bound ],
   startPolling: [Function: bound ],
   stopPolling: [Function: bound ],
   subscribeToMore: [Function: bound ],
   loading: true,
   networkStatus: 1,
   error: [Getter] } }

props from component { data:
 { variables: { offset: null, limit: null },
   refetch: [Function: bound ],
   fetchMore: [Function: bound ],
   updateQuery: [Function: bound ],
   startPolling: [Function: bound ],
   stopPolling: [Function: bound ],
   subscribeToMore: [Function: bound ],
   loading: false,
   networkStatus: 8,
   error: [Getter] } }
```

Comment: Same problem here, did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @hamishtaplin I did actually. Instead of trying to test the wrapped component, I tested the unwrapped component and mocked its props. No need to test Apollo, it has its own tests.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks!

Comment: If anyone ends up here looking for answers to a similar problem, make sure to match the variables in the mock to the exact ones for the query that is actually being run. In my case there was an extra pagination variable that I didn't include in the mocks, but my component added by default. It seems to me that the OP's issue is the same since from the output the query seems to be run with `{ offset: null, limit: null }` as variables, but I didn't replicate the scenario to confirm.