# React Apollo MockProvider always loading, never giving data

Tags: reactjs, mocking, graphql, enzyme, react-apollo

I'm trying to test a component that uses graphql, but when using Apollo's MockProvider I never get the data, it just says loading = true every time.

A complete, minimalist example is [here](https://github.com/DovidM/graphql-question-example.git)

Things I've tried:

1. Looking online (found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43727517/using-apollos-mockedprovider-why-dont-the-components-props-get-populated-with), but since it had no answer I thought I'd make a new one with more information)
2. Tried exporting components without the graphql when testing (`export function Component`), but that doesn't work when testing nested components
3. Tried simplifying as much as possible (the results of which is in the example)

Comment: what are you using? Enzyme?

Comment: @arcom yes. Added the tag

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yup I ran into this issue as well. The funny thing was that if I add console logs to the component itself, I could see that the data ended up getting there just fine. But for some reason the `wrapper` would still only contain our "Loading ..." UI.

Turns out you need to call `wrapper.update()` to get the wrapper to rerender it's contents.

This is what worked for me, but it seems less than ideal, so if anyone else has a workaround let me know! Right now our tests look something like:

```js
it('should render the HeroDiv if there is guide data', async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <MockedProvider mocks={mocksWithGuideData} addTypename={false}>
      <Hero {...props} />
    </MockedProvider>
  );

  await wait(0);
  wrapper.update();

  expect(wrapper.find('HeroDiv').exists()).toBeTruthy();
})
```

Comment: Yeah, that's weird but it worked. For anyone else reading this, substitute the `wait` for wrapping the `expect` in setTimeout with 0 time

Comment: amazing, i've been stuck on this for days...Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a fan of the `await wait(0)` approach. Looking at the apollo docs:

`For more complex UI with heavy calculations, or delays added into its render logic, the wait(0) will not be long enough.`

This means that your tests can potentially be flaky. To solve this issue I use the `wait-for-expect` package (also covered in the docs: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/guides/testing-react-components.html#Testing-mutation-components):

```
it('should render the HeroDiv if there is guide data', async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <MockedProvider mocks={mocksWithGuideData} addTypename={false}>
      <Hero {...props} />
    </MockedProvider>
  );

  await waitForExpect(() => {
    wrapper.update();
    expect(wrapper.find('HeroDiv').exists()).toBeTruthy();
  });
})
```

`waitForExpect` will essentially poll until the condition is complete and it times out after 5 seconds. This guarantees that your test will complete, as long as your query completes before 5 seconds, which it absolutely should if you're using MockedProvider.

The docs point out one caveat: `The risk of using a package like this everywhere by default is that every test could take up to five seconds to execute (or longer if the default timeout has been increased).` But in my experience this won't ever happen with MockedProvider. Also aside, `await wait(0)` would not handle this case consistently anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure that the query that you are importing in component file is the exact same one that you are using in the test file. For example, I had that an issue where my mocks prop wouldn't pass any data to the MockedProvider because I was importing:

```
import { CURRENT_USER_QUERY } from '../lib/queries';
```

in PleaseSigin.js, and I was importing:

```
import { CURRENT_USER_QUERY } from './User';
```

in PleaseSignin.test.js. Apparently, even though both queries are identical, they are not the same as far as Jest is concerned.